# rename first part of the filename in linux?

Tags: linux, mv

I have lot of files starting with `processConfig-`. I wanted to rename it to `processCfg-`. What's the easy way to change the first part of file name to `processCfg-` in linux?

But I don't want to rename this file `processConfig.json` since it doesn't match with my prefix.

```
> ls -lrth
total 467
-rw-r--r--  1 david  staff   9.8K May 26 15:14 processConfig-data-1234.json
-rw-r--r--  1 david  staff    11K May 26 15:14 processConfig-data-8762.json
-rw-r--r--  1 david  staff   4.9K May 26 15:14 processConfig-dataHold-1.json
-rw-r--r--  1 david  staff   6.6K May 26 15:14 processConfig-letter.json
-rw-r--r--  1 david  staff   5.6K May 26 16:44 processConfig-data-90987.json
-rw-r--r--  1 david  staff   284K May 28 18:44 processConfig.json
```

Comment: You should show us what you have tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this :

```
rename -n 's/^processConfig-/processCfg-/' processConfig-*.json
```

Remove `-n` switch when the output looks good to rename for real.

[man rename](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/rename/file-rename.1p.en.html)

[image: warning] **There are other tools with the same name which may or may not be able to do this, so be careful.**

The rename command that is part of the `util-linux` package, won't.

If you run the following command (`GNU`)

```
$ file "$(readlink -f "$(type -p rename)")"
```

and you have a result that contains `Perl script, ASCII text executable` and not containing `ELF`, then this seems to be the right tool =)

If not, to make it the default (usually already the case) on `Debian` and derivative like `Ubuntu` :

```
$ sudo apt install rename
$ sudo update-alternatives --set rename /usr/bin/file-rename
```

---

If you don't have this command with another distro, search your package manager to install it or [do it manually](https://metacpan.org/module/RMBARKER/File-Rename-0.20/rename.PL) (no deps...)

---

<sub><sup>This tool was originally written by Larry Wall, the Perl's dad.</sup></sub>

Comment: on macos `brew install rename` will this install same thing right?

Comment: Give it a try :)

Comment: pls ignore.. need more coffee. sorry about that.

Comment: thanks to you learned about `rename` command. Never heard of it before.